# Getting error with the folloeing code for databse connection function call

Tags: php, database

```
public function Fetch_num1($id) {
    
    echo "Hi";
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM editors where jid='$id'";
    
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql); 
    
    $nr = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    
    return $nr;
}
```

Its shows warnings like:

> mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
> mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given
> in

Comment: There's no _databse connection function call_ in your code, and that may be the issue.

Comment: [Greetings, `Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--`, how do you do?](https://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As Armali says in the comments, you are not making a database connection. Here is a typical connection code copied from w3schools (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp):

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Replace `localhost`, `username`, and `password` with your db name, user name, and password, then replace `$connection` with `$conn`.

Also, I think `where` should be all caps: `WHERE`.